# Detecting Inheritance during compile time

Tags: c++

I am unable to figure out why this code is returning false. I had the first version of partial specialization. It did not work, I tried with the second version. It did not work either.

**UPDATE:** I wanted to check if "Derived" is publicly derived from "Base".

**UPDATE:**

```
    template<typename TDerived, typename TBase>
    struct Derived_From
    {

    public:
        static void constraints(TBase*, TDerived* ptr) { TBase* b = ptr; ignore(b); }
        Derived_From() { void (*p)(TBase*, TDerived*) = constraints; ignore(p);}
    };
```

I found the above code snippet in Strostrup's homepage. But, it does not let the code compile if the derived class is not publicly derived from Base.

```
template<class TBase, class TDerived>
struct IsDerived
{
    public:
    enum { isDerived = false };
};


template<class TBase>
struct IsDerived<TBase, TBase>
{
    public:
    enum {  isDerived = true };
};


template<class TBase>
struct IsDerived<TBase&, TBase&>
{
    public:
    enum {  isDerived = true };
};

int main()
{
    cout << ((IsDerived<Base&, Derived&>::isDerived) ? "true" : "false")
         << endl;
    cout << ((IsDerived<const Derived*, const Base*>::isDerived) ?
            "true" : "false") << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always just use pointer initialization for this.  Pointers implicitly convert only to a supertype (could be identity conversion or public base class), so it won't compile unless that relationship exists (and in the right direction).

e.g.

```
Parent* p = (Possibly_Derived*)0;
```

Oh wait, you're not wanting compilation to fail, but to set a variable?  Here:

```
template<typename TParent>
bool is_derived_from( TParent* ) { return true; }

template<typename TParent>
bool is_derived_from( void* ) { return false; }

cout << is_derived_from<Parent>( (Possibly_Derived*)0 );
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/0ShRF

Answer (score 7):

Check out [boost type traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html), specifically the [`is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) template.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I assume you want a generic method to work for any classes, without modifying or adding any function to the class.  I think this template method cannot work. A derived class is not *equal* to the base class, and unless the two classes are EQUAL, the specialized struct will not be instantiated. Similarly, pointer to derived class is not *equal* to pointer to base class.

I assume you already know that people regularly use virtual functions to check if the "object" is of base class or derived class.

(Note that I am *not* saying what you want cannot be done - just that the results you are seeing are expected and the template approach will not work).

Comment: I want to check if "Derived" is publicly derived from "Base". How do I check that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you are calling the Template with 2 different Parameter types..

```
(IsDerived<Base&, Derived&>::isDerived)
```

Thus it will invoke

```
struct IsDerived
{
    public:
    enum { isDerived = false };
};
```

and this is why `IsDerived<Base&, Derived&>::isDerived` as well as `IsDerived<const Derived*, const Base*>::isDerived` is false.

calls like `(IsDerived<Base&, Base&>::isDerived)` will return True.

> I wanted to check if "Derived" is
>   publicly derived from "Base".

I am not aware of Template based solution, and will keep a eye on this thread. but i usually exploit dynamic_cast to do this job, if ever needed.

If dynamic_cast cannot cast a pointer because it is not a complete object of the required class, it returns a null pointer to indicate the failure.

If dynamic_cast is used to convert to a reference type and the conversion is not possible, an exception of type bad_cast is thrown instead.